# Jquery validate plugin remote not working with php if statement

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-validate

I've got a pretty simple form set up that I'm using Jquery validate to check my fields and that seems to be working file. I then wanted to set up the remote with a php file to check the availability of a username. When I echo the check_num_rows, I get the number of rows back that match the input.

```
$check_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($check);
```

I don't want just the number of matches obviously, so I added an if statement making it look like this...

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);

$check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$check_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($check);

if ($check_num_rows == 1)
{
    echo "Username taken!";
}
```

The regular validation still works, but I don't get the echo back like I did before which leads me to believe it's an error with just those last few lines of code, but I don't see it. Below is the Jquery validate portion.

```
$("#register").validate({         
rules: {
    username: {
        minlength: 5,
        remote: "check-username.php"     
},
    password: {
        minlength: 6
    }
}
});
```

I have seen other answers to questions similar to this, but nothing that fits here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As per documentation for the `remote` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/),

> The serverside resource is called via jQuery.ajax (XMLHttpRequest) and
>   gets a key/value pair, corresponding to the name of the validated
>   element and its value as a GET parameter. The response is evaluated as
>   JSON and **must be true for valid elements**, and can be any false,
>   undefined or null for invalid elements, using the default message; or
>   a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead" to
>   display as the error message.

Note the part in bold above.  I don't see how/where your PHP ever returns a `true` response.

Comment: Thank you! Per your suggestion I added the "else" statement. Now when I it returns true, nothing is echoed to screen and when it's false I have "Username taken" which is exactly what I wanted. I also added json_encode. Code now looks like this... `$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);

$check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$check_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($check);

if ($check_num_rows > 0)
{
    $invalid = "Username is taken!";
}    
    else {
        $invalid = "true";
    }

echo \json_encode($invalid);`